# Invalid Executable** - The executable 'JumpRush.app/JumpRush' does not contain bitcode

Tags: notifications, push, executable, bitcode

**Invalid Executable** - The executable 'JumpRush.app/JumpRush' does not contain bitcode.

Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to make you aware of them: 
**Missing Push Notification Entitlement** - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement.

I have tried enabling bitcode in target settings and also tried setting c flag to -fembed-bitcode but still getting the same error.
Xcode 7.2, unity3d 5.3.0